# how to call handlebar helper function from jquery select event

Tags: templates, select

Say I have a handlebar template which has two list select controls, the selected value of the first one will decide the dynamic content of the second list control, I defined the select event JavaScript handler for the first list

```
    <select class="form-control" id="list1" name="list1" onchange="onFirstSel(this);">
                                    <option value="">{{{__ "Choose a item"}}}</option>
                                    {{#each lst}}
                                    <option value="{{this.itemId}}">{{this.itemId}}</option>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </select>
  <select id="list2" >
     initial options
  </select>
```

I registered an Handlebar helper function which will generate the dynamic content of the list2 according the selected value of the list1

hbs.registerAsyncHelper('gen_list2_content', function(itemId, callback){
       ....
})

And in the script part, I implement the select event handler of the first one.

```
<script>
          function onFirstSel(sel) {
             var itemId = sel.value;
             $("#list2").empty();
             //$("#list2").append( return value of handlebar gen_list2_content)
          }
   </script>
```

I want to call the HandleBar helper function gen_list2_content to refresh the
list2 content when the first list select changed, is it possible?